# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/struts]

Tags: eclipse, spring, jsp, struts2, action-mapping

I've looked through all similar Qs on stackoverflow but it didn't help, sorry. The main difference I have from all of them is that I got EMPTY action name in error message. Googling didn't help :(
        Hope someone just could give a hint where to look for the source of the problem. thx

message:

```
    Stacktraces
    There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/struts]. - [unknown location] 
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58
    ..................
```

struts.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

        <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <package name="default" namespace="/*" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="login"
                class="training.struts.action.LoginAction">
                <result>login.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
        </struts>
```

web.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">

        <display-name>Struts Lab</display-name>

        <filter>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <!-- Spring Config -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/springServlet/appServlet/mvc-servlet.xml,
                    /WEB-INF/db/db-cfg.xml,
                    /WEB-INF/springServlet/application-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/springServlet/appServlet/mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <!-- *** -->
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        </web-app>
```

well..image is impossible so the project structure is:

```
src/main/java
----+training.struts.action.LoginAction.java
src/main/webapp
----+WEB-INF
--------+classes
-----------+struts.xml
--------+db
-----------+db-cfg.xml
--------+springServlet
-----------+appServlet
---------------+mvc-servlet.xml
-----------+application-security.xml
--------+index.jsp
--------+login.jsp
--------+web.xml
```

**UPDATE:
So sad to be stupid =(
I've moved my login.jsp from WEB-INF to webapp root and that solved the problem.**

**UPDATE2:**
I've made some investigation:
if I remove "welcome-file-list" block from web.xml, container will look for "index.jsp" in webapp root to show as first view on application running. If I delete "index.jsp" then I'll got the identical exception message:
*There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/struts]*

So in my opinion if you have empty action name in error message with correct xml settings for struts, the first step should be start-up JSP availability checking.

Cheers, guys.

Comment: `namespace="/*"` in package and spring mvc with Struts2. Where from do you copy that crappy code/conf...

Comment: @Alexandr T I'm the total newbie and I've written it by myself...I\ve got my little app on Srping and I needed to integrate Struts in it to learn struts..

Comment: @Alexandr M do you mean Spring MVC interference with Struts2 own mvc or smthg like that? should I investigate this way?

Comment: Servlets should be mapped to it's own context.

Comment: @Roman C Roman could described in details your comment? sorry but I can't get it =(

Comment: @java_newbie servlets should not be filtered by the struts2.

Comment: @Roman thx, I got it while I was on the way to office. So Spring dispatcher is no needed 'cause I'm not gonna use Controllers now, only Struts actions. Right?

Comment: @java_newbie It's up to you to decide if it's needed or not, IMO I would choose between Spring MVC and Struts2.

Comment: @Roman thx man, I should read more theory I think =)

Comment: @java_newbie Thanks alot man!! your investigation worked for me :) you made  my day! Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I have placed login.jsp in a wrong place in my web-app folders structure.
That was the mistake

Answer (score 4):

Add the below blank action to you struts.xml file in `"/"` package namespace and it will show the index.html when you will only try to access your url (like appid.app.com) and it will not show the error. Normally it will add a blank action and app engine will redirect the blank action to your welcome file.

```
    <action name="" class="com.candi.actions.Dashboard" method="noAction">
        <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add / in your namespace instead of /* :

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

Or if issue not resolved than you can use [Config Browser Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/config-browser-plugin.html).

The Config Browser Plugin is a simple tool to help view an application's configuration at runtime. It is very useful when debugging problems that could be related to configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following package in struts.xml

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">    
     <action name="login"
            class="training.struts.action.LoginAction">
            <result>login.jsp</result>
    </action>   
</package>
```

Comment: Attach the JSP page where you are calling the action

Comment: I don't call any actions manually - I just run the project on server in eclipse

Comment: 2337 neurons suddendly died in my brain after reading `<action name="*"`

Comment: @AndreaLigios: `<action name="*"` is wildcard default for action which can be used to catch unmatched references.

Comment: @AleksandrM I know that, [I've used it too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17405177/1654265), but for default fallback of not found action URLs; in this answer, it seemed to be used to avoid declaring any action... no matter the URL, it will always fallback on LoginAction :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios For other project actions specify the package namespace.For more modularization.For e.g namespace = "/Action"...Other than any url will redirect you to login page
Since in user code it wont redirect to welcome page on context root.This is the one way to redirect it on contextroot

Comment: Yes, but since you probably have to check if user is authenticated in an Interceptor, this becomes useless; it is useful only if you want to redirect to login page a user that is trying to hack with the URL, instead of giving him a 404 page (from where you can reach the login page, of course). Btw I didn't downvote you, just commented; as a hint, put this kind of considerations in the answer next time, to avoid putting them later in the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the namespace in package tag to '/' and the problem resolved!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I changed the opening tag of the web.xml file from

```
<web-app>
```

to

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```